# Indication warm start infeasible in CPLEX

Tags: java, linear-programming, cplex

I'm running LP problem in CPLEX with JAVA API. I'm trying to model a greedy solution by fixing a maximal number of variables until I get a feasible solution.
I use this to fix the variables:

```
cplex.addMIPStart(startVar, startVal);
```

Obviously, when I fix all variables the solution is infeasible and I get this warning when I run `solve()`:

```
Warning:  No solution found from 1 MIP starts.
```

However, `solve()` immediately proceeds to solve the problem and provides an optimal solution. I've tried using `cplex.getCplexStatus()`, but I get 'Optimal'.

How can I know if my proposed MIPStart is infeasible during runtime, so I could provide a less strict MIPStart (until I reach a feasible solution)?

Comment: If you fix too many variables leading to an infeasible problem, Cplex will never return "Optimal", Note that you don't need to use MIPSTART at all. Just fix and solve. In case you don't know: fix means in linear programming: set the lower bound an upper bound to a single value.

Comment: Don't forget that the MIPStart you provide is only a guess at a solution to help CPLEX. It doesn't 'fix' the variables values (in Erwin's sense above), but is instead just taken as a hint of where to start. If (as in your case) the MIPStart doesn't lead to a feasible solution, CPLEX will ignore it and do a normal search, so your solution should be optimal. Try playing around with this stuff - maybe take your (optimal) solution from CPLEX and create a MIPStart with those values and it should then work and get a solution faster. Maybe try with values for only 90%, or 50% or 10% of the variables.

Comment: Fixing and MIPSTART are two very different concepts. Fixing means: a variable can not move away from a given value. MIPSTART is just giving a starting solution (for performance reasons).